# Translation and rotation matrix

Tags: lua, rotation, translation, matrix-multiplication

Does anyone have code to perform the matrix calculation for translation and rotation of a point I. 2D, please?

Ive been looking all over the net and not found it in a form I can use. I'm coding in lua, but any other language would be fine.

Many thanks,

Matt.

Comment: uhh, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix.  your net must suck

Comment: Thanks, have 100 internets on me. I probably skipped pages like that earlier and got mired in the rough...